# Set Footer To Bottom Of Page Using JavaScript only

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to hack a Squarespace template to turn an announcement bar into a footer.

Can anyone advise how to force an element to the bottom of the page using JavaScript only.

No CSS, no jQuery.

Thanks
James

Comment: You can apply **CSS** styles through **JavaScript**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without CSS you can not *place* anything in a specific location on the page. You can move things to the end of the HTML (The last tags of the `<body>` element) But they will still just show inline with the rest of the page.

CSS is **required** if you want to change the visible location of an element or set of elements.

Comment: Thanks - that will explain why I couldn't do it!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by no CSS. I understood you want to apply CSS changes with DOM manipulation.

You can apply a `position: fixed` and float it to bottom.

```
var container = document.querySelector('.announcement');
container.style.position = 'fixed';
container.style.bottom = 0;
```

Working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sygn/kkp32gu3/)

Comment: Applying **CSS** styles through **JavaScript**. This is correct.